# Showing Lagrange multiplier gives the unique solution of constrained, convex, quadratic loss function

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

### Backgrounds

I would like to specify the conditions the **Lagrange multiplier** uniquely identifies the **global minimum**. (Actually, the main motivation is the derivation of [Ridge estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tikhonov_regularization) in Statistics).

It may be a very elementary problem in **convex optimization**, but I feel I do not have reached sufficient understanding.

---

### Question

Say we would like to find the parameter $\beta^\dagger \in \mathbb{R}^p$ that **globally minimize**  the **constrained** loss function **$L1(\beta)$** and **not constrained** loss function **$L2(\beta)$**.

> Show that the following two have the **same, unique** solution.
>
> 1. $\mathrm{argmin}_\beta L_1 (\beta) = \mathrm{argmin}_\beta \left( \beta^T A \beta - 2b^T \beta \right)$ **subject to** $\beta^T \beta < R$.
> 2. $\mathrm{argmin}_\beta L_2 (\beta) = \mathrm{argmin}_\beta \left( \beta^T A \beta - 2 b^T \beta + \lambda \beta^T \beta\right)$

where $A_{p \times p}$ : symmetric positive definite, $b \in \mathbb{R}^p$ and $\lambda >0, R>0$.

---

### Try

**Step1. The uniqueness of $\mathrm{argmin}_\beta L_2 (\beta)$**.

In
$$L_2(\beta) = \beta^T (A + \lambda I ) \beta - 2 b^T \beta$$

we have $A + \lambda I$ : **symmetric positive definite**, since $\lambda I $ is symmetric positive definite. Thus we have $\beta^T (A + \lambda I ) \beta$ is **strictly convex**, and thus $L_2 (\beta) $ : **strictly convex** function of $\beta$.

From **strict convexity** and the fact that $\frac{\partial L_2}{\partial \beta} = 2(A + \lambda I)\beta - 2b=0$ has the **unique** solution $\beta = (A + \lambda I)^{-1} b$, thus we have $\mathrm{argmin}_\beta L_2 (\beta) = (A + \lambda I)^{-1} b$ is the **global minimizer** of $L_2$

---

**Step2. The equivalence of 1 and 2**.

As far as I know, the [Lagrange multiplier method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) is a strategy for finding the local maxima and minima of a function subject to **equality constraints**.

---

### Problems

But I have following two problems

- the problem has **inequality constraints**, so I'm not sure the method is applicable
- I have noticed the quadratic function $L_1(\beta) = \left( \beta^T A \beta - 2b^T \beta \right)$ also has the **global minimum**, since $A$ is symmetric positive definite. But I'm not sure how I should relate this to $\mathrm{argmin}_\beta \left( \beta^T A \beta - 2b^T \beta \right)$ **subject to** $\beta^T \beta < \lambda$ has the unique and same solution as $2$.

Any help will be appreciated.

---

### Edited 1

Following the **comment** and the **answer** I came to understand that generally $R \neq \lambda$. (Actually there was $\lambda$ in place of $R$ above)

Now I edited $L_1(\beta)$, I would like to ask, that the **1** and **2** has the same and unique solution.

---

### Edited 2

The whole above discussion may be misleading, due to my poor setting of the problem.

Thanks to the answer by @AngryAvian, the above statement should be **"for a given value of $R$, there exists a value of $\lambda$ that makes the solutions of $L1$ and and $L2$ the same"**, and vice versa.

Comment: It is not true in general. An easy example is to take $\lambda$ large enough so that the constraint is not active at the minimum and thus the solution does not depend on $\lambda$. However, in the second problem, the minimum will still  depend on $\lambda$. The way $\lambda$ enters $L_2$ it is the Lagrange multiplier, but it is usually not the same $\lambda$ in $L_1$. There is a generalization of Lagrange multiplier method to inequalities, take a look at [KKT condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions).

Comment: @A.Γ. Seems I have poor knowledge to understand the link's explanations.. So my $L_1$ problem satisfies the KKT conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe your claim is true, only because the same $\lambda$ appears in both problems.

Here is a counterexample in $p=1$. Take $A=1$ and $b=1$ and $\lambda=2$.
The minimum of $\beta^2 - 2 \beta$ subject to $\beta^2 < 2$ is attained at $\beta=1$. The minimum of $\beta^2 - 2 \beta + 2 \beta^2$ is attained at $\beta=1/3$.

Edit: A.Γ.'s counterexample is much better explanation and contains my above counterexample as a special case. The global minimizer of $\beta^\top A \beta - 2 b^\top \beta$ is $\beta_* := A^{-1} b$. As long as $\lambda > \beta_*^\top \beta_*$, the solution to $L_1$ is $\beta_* = A^{-1} b$. On the other hand, the solution to $L_2$ is $(A+\lambda I)^{-1} b$ which depends on $\lambda$, never mind being equal to $A^{-1} b$.

---

If you rewrite the constraint in $L_1$ as $\beta^\top \beta < R$, then there is some corresponding $\lambda$ such that $L_2$ gives the same solution, but it usually (actually almost never) is not the same as $R$. More generally, the Lagrange multiplier that arises when dealing with a constrained problem does not usually equal the constraint (or depend so explicitly on it).

Comment: Thank you, I did not know the point. Now I edited question, changing $\lambda$ into $R$. Then how can I prove?

Comment: @Moreblue Your question still does not make sense since $\lambda$ and $R$ have nothing to do with each other. (That is, the solution to $L_1$ might depend on $R$, and the solution to $L_2$ might depend on $\lambda$, but if you don't know how $\lambda$ and $R$ are related, how can we possibly prove the solutions are the same?)

Comment: @Moreblue As I already mentioned in my question, for a given value of $R$, there exists a value of $\lambda$ that makes the solutions of $L_1$ and $L_2$ the same. Similarly, for a given value of $\lambda$, there exists a value of $R$ that makes the solutions the same. [I may be forgetting some technicalities.] However, the relationship between $R$ and $\lambda$ is not explicit and is not a bijection. (For example, for any $R > \|A^{-1} b\|^2$, taking $\lambda=0$ makes both solutions the same, namely $A^{-1} b$.